# Votos em série...Positivos

Tags: debate

Posso dar votos em série em repostas ou perguntas de um mesmo usuário?

Existe algum limite para votos? Por exemplo vez ou outra eu entro no perfil de algum usuário, por acreditar que as perguntas e respostas são boas, e as que gosto voto positivo, existe algum limite?

Comment: Sim, se o sistema detectar que você está votando seguidamente no conteudo de um mesmo usuario em um curto espaço de tempo, ele reverte todos os pontos, sejam negativos ou positivos.

Comment: Mas sabe se existe um limite ? Quantos votos , quanto tempo ? @diegofm

Comment: Em principio, por mais que se simpatize (ou se antipatize) com um usuário, o que deve prevalecer é o conteúdo, então é natural que o sistema não incentive (e até reprove) votação serial em usuários. A idéia é que ao esbarrar num bom post, você positive, num ruim, não construtivo, negative, e num "neutro", deixe como está. O que vier a mais que isso é "bônus" (deixar um comentário antes de negativar, sinalização quando apropriado, orientação de como melhorar, etc).

Comment: O que pode acontecer é você pesquisar algo sobre determinado assunto e esbarrar com mais de um post da mesma pessoa, se a pessoa trata bastante daquilo e é uma referência confiável. Mesmo assim, tem que tomar cuidado, pq o sistema não é "adivinho". Da mesma forma, eu já tive caso de votação negativa revertida indevidamente pelo mesmo motivo. O usuário postou muita coisa ruim em pouco tempo, e eu sequer notei que era tudo da mesma pessoa. Só percebi que tinha sido revertido pq eu tinha favoritado um dos posts para retirar o negativo caso ela melhorasse, e quando entrei o -1 nao estava mais lá.

Comment: Eu fico imaginando quantas vezes por dia o sistema reverte votos para um usuário como o [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). E mesmo assim o resultado é o mesmo, ele vai conseguir 200 de reputação todos os dias :).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly nussa mano... 1 milhão de reputação, 500 gold 33 mil respostas hahaha ..... sabe nada esse inocente... acabei de dar um downvote só de raiva.... zueira ;)

Comment: @MagicHat, pois é! Daí você vai fuçar no perfil da cara e acaba achando várias das respostas interessantes... Será que acabou em serial upvote? De certa forma eu fico feliz em saber que os critérios para "votos em massa" não sejam públicos; mesmos usuários bem intencionados acabariam contando votos em situações como essa :). A "ignorância" sobre os critérios acaba, na média, resultando em comportamento saudável.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Caso o sistema detecte que um usuário está votando seguidamente em muitos posts de outro usuario(seja upvote ou downvote) em um curto periodo de tempo, pode ser considerado como uma tentativa de [fraude de votação](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/310559), e os reverte durante a madrugada(UTC).

Segundo [esta resposta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268747/5524514) no SOEn:

> The exact definition of serial voting (time/quantity) isn't published to prevent people from gaming the system (i.e. pushing the votes right to the limit where it still has an impact but isn't reversed).

Ou seja, não é revelado a forma como o sistema detecta esse tipo de coisa, para evitar que pessoas possam fazer mau uso e, seja para beneficiar ou prejudicar alguém.

Importante notar que o fato de fazer isso repetidas vezes pode causar outros desdobramentos. O sistema automático é só uma das primeiras "punições" possíveis, para facilitar o serviço da moderação. Isso não isenta de ações manuais por parte da moderação ou do staff - em outras palavras, o sistema detectar ou não não dá "passe livre" para nenhum tipo de fraude.