# Votar no conteudo VS Votar por afeição

Tags: debate, votos

Há muito tempo vejo discussões na comunidade sobre :

> - Não votam nas minhas Pergunta/Resposta porque não gostam de mim.
> - Eu ganho votos negativos por perseguição.
> - As pessoas estão votando na pessoa e não no conteúdo.
> - A Pergunta/Resposta é ruim, mesmo assim tem muitos votos.

Há algum tempo eu pensei em uma possível solução para isso e, como o assunto veio a tona novamente, estou montando-a e colocando em debate.

### Sugestão

> Toda Pergunta/Resposta fica com usuário anônimo e após o usuário da sessão decidir seu voto, o AP/AR é exibido.

#### Vantagens

- O usuário votaria no conteúdo e não por afetividade.
- Geraria conteúdo devidamente avaliado.

#### Desvantagens

- Poderia estimular o voto negativo já que usuário gostaria apenas de ser quem é o AP (e não há voto branco);
- A fila de perguntas ficaria com vários AP anônimos, AR fica anônimos caso haja apenas um, dois ou mais pode ser exibido já que ao entrar na pergunta não se sabe de quem é a resposta.
- Teria de ser verificar o procedimento para visualizar os demais AR. (Ex.: 7 respostas, mas só gostei de 1, mas gostaria de saber os AR das demais).

#### Opinião própria

É apenas uma sugestão, que geraria um grande manutenção para o SO, que eu não vejo muita vantagem, já que bastaria as pessoa votarem com base lógica e não emocional.

```js
var profile = {
  avatar : 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/TydU1.jpg',
  name : 'Guilherme Lautert',
}

var Name = $('.user-name');
var Avatar = $('.user-gravatar32');
var Flair = $('.-flair');

var Up = $('.vote-up-off');
var Down = $('.vote-down-off');

function showUser(){
  Name.html(profile.name);
  Flair.css('display', 'block');
  
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = profile.avatar;
  img.width = img.height = 32;
  
  Avatar.html(img.outerHTML);
}

Up.on('click', function(){
  Up.addClass('vote-up-on');
  showUser();
});

Down.on('click', function(){
  Down.addClass('vote-down-on');
  showUser();
});
```

```css
.content > div{
  float:left;
}

.content{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.post-signature{
  margin-top:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="content">
  <div class="votecell">
    <div class="vote">
      <a class="vote-up-off" title="Esta pergunta mostra esforço de pesquisa; é útil e clara">votar a favor</a>
      <span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post " title="Exibir totais de votos a favor e contra" style="cursor: pointer;">1</span>
      <a class="vote-down-off" title="Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara ou não é útil">votar contra</a>

      <a class="star-off" href="#" title="Clique para marcar como pergunta favorita (clique novamente para desfazer)">favorita</a>
      <div class="favoritecount"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post-signature owner">
    <div class="user-info ">
        <div class="user-action-time">
            perguntada <span title="2013-12-11 15:58:03Z" class="relativetime">11/12/13 às 15:58</span>
        </div>
        <div class="user-gravatar32">
            <span class="anonymous-gravatar"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="user-details">
            <span class="user-name">user59</span>
            <div class="-flair" style="display:none;">
            <span class="reputation-score" title="pontos de reputação " dir="ltr">8.217</span><span title="1 medalhas de ouro"><span class="badge1"></span><span class="badgecount">1</span></span><span title="14 medalhas de prata"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">14</span></span><span title="67 medalhas de bronze"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">67</span></span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu gosto da ideia geral, mas isto não será implementado. Nos detalhes tem alguns problemas. A psoa pode tirar o voto logo após saber quem é. Mesmo que espere os 5min para mostrar quem é, ele poderá tirar se tiver uma edição, e não podemos impedir isso porque a edição pode realmente justificar uma mudança de voto. Além disto precisa não mostrar o placar, porque eu **acho** que tem muito mais voto porque algo já tem votos ou está aceito, ou ainda é o que está mais acima do que pela pessoa em si. Vira e mexe tem usuário experiente que diz que não votou em algo com menos votos porque não viu lá.

Comment: Eu **acho** que no geral diminuiria a quantidade de votos certos junto com os votos errados. Há voto branco (o não voto). Se a pessoa nunca votar ela nunca verá o placar? Então pra que serve o placar se você não pode ver. Não se esqueça que a maioria dos usuários do site são *readonly*, muitos inclusive nem tem conta, só chegam e olham e quem ver o placar pra decidir se é bom ou não.

Comment: Ok, falou só do usuário, mas saber quem é pode tb ajudar decidir se ela confia naquilo ou não. Fora que quem respondeu quer ter seu nome divulgado, senão viramos Wikipedia que você só sabe quem escreveu circunstancialmente. Não entendi o 2o. ponto de desvantagem de respostas, O 3o. me parece impossível de resolver sem abrir falhas no procedimento. Ou seja, tentaria segurar água com uma peneira. Não poderia mostrar nem o número do usuário.

Comment: @bigown Todas estas observações que você fez estão corretas, alguma ate já havia pensado, claro que a ideia é só um esboço e necessitaria muito mais analise, mas como concordamos que é algo inviável por vários fatores ja abordados não me aprofundei nela. Ate ja bolei algumas soluções para determinados casos.
O questão maior que quis colocar, seria em relação ao voto logico, e não emocional. Todo este desenvolvimento poderia partir da própria pessoa, e não desenvolvido de fato.

Comment: Excelente ideia. Deveria ser implementado para a melhoria da comunidade. Não irá!

Comment: Eu já comentei algumas vezes sobre isso (talvez até no chat), e é uma das coisas que eu penso desde o "começo", quando notei os problemas recorrentes do site. Gosto da idéia, mas não vejo maneira realista de implementar na rede. Seria outra cultura (e ainda teria o problema de ter outros meios de se saber de quem é cada coisa). Mais que isso, teria que esconder os pontos e tudo o mais. De qq forma, o raciocínio faz todo sentido, ao menos como "experiência mental". Talvez nunca seja implementado, mas pode dar asas a outras idéias.

Comment: O exemplo ficou muito bacana :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu tenho um projeto inspirado em 'fóruns' de internet. Penso em implementar essa ideia, mas quero te dar os devidos créditos.

Comment: Eu acho que a proposta tem vários furos e, possivelmente, traz mais problemas do que soluções. Mas eu votei positivamente porque você é um cara bacana.

Comment: @jbueno é que não se trata bem de uma solução, mas uma critica, para a pratica do "exercício mental" de ignorar o AP/AR mediante decisão do voto, levando em consideração apenas o conteúdo. Seria muito mais simples de as pessoas adotassem essa medida do que desenvolver tudo isso.

Comment: Algumas pessoas "pegam antipatia" por outras e mesmo que a resposta seja excelente dentro da necessidade da pergunta noto que certas pessoas evitam o upvote e o mesmo vale para o downvote, eu admito, evito de dar downvote para várias pessoas, mesmo que não seja alguem que eu converse tanto, isto é meio que para evitar um certo "mal-estar", também notei que por falta de simpatia pela minha maneira mais seca e direta de tratar alguns assuntos ganhei o desinteresse de alguns o que fez meus upvotes diminuírem, ou seja eu talvez ganhasse ups por simpatia (o que hoje eu perdi)...

Comment: ... Por isto gostei da sua ideia, só que acredito que infelizmente não será muito eficiente pois geralmente muitas perguntas/respostas geram upvotes a partir do chat, mesmo que o AP seja oculto a pessoa saberá em quem esta votando sim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento essa questão do chat, pode ou não ocorrer, ate porque, mesmo que eu mande no chat, a menos que eu deixe explicito que fui eu, você não saberá se estou fazendo "propagando" da minha questão ou de outro usuário.

Comment: utilizo o fórum a muitos anos (en) e sou ativamente novo, me impressiona saber que acontece este tipo de coisa. rs. Esses dias ganhei vários votos em vários comentários da mesma pessoa e acabei sendo punido. Acho que essa solução também acabaria com isso. As vezes a pessoa quer te prejudicar pq vê que está ganhando muitos pontos e faz isso. Inibir ver todas as interações no perfil da pessoa tbm seria útil.

Comment: Discussão antiga que não nos leva a nada. Não vou dar uma solução porque acho que não há. É "chover no molhado".
O que se passa com a votação aqui é o mesmo que se passa na vida real: nem sempre a qualidade é devidamente reconhecida e valorizada. No entanto, ela(a qualidade) está lá, não é o reconhecimento(votos) que a torna boa. Cabe a cada um de nós avaliá-la, independentemente dos "votos" que tenha ou não.

Comment: O @DiegoAndrade frequenta o "fórum" a anos, mas que fórum? 0.o ... nem SOpt nem SOen são fóruns :p

Comment: @ramaral concordo com você, mas uma resposta boa negativada, pra quem está de fora, é uma resposta ruim. Eu tive uma resposta negativada por vingança recentemente, mas vou fazer o que? Infelizmente é como você falou, mas nem sempre é aplicada a justiça, e uma resposta boa é desperdiçada por causa de comportamento ruim.

Comment: @diegofm A resposta não foi desperdiçada, ele continua lá com o seu conteúdo intacto. Apesar do voto negativo ela não deixou de ser boa. É claro que é injusto. "mas vou fazer o quê?", pergunta você, eu deixo um comentário a perguntar a razão e esqueço o assunto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vc pode chamar até de Robson se quiser. Eu chamo de "fórum". É por esses e outros comentários que não anima muito ficar interagindo. rs brhue

Comment: @DiegoAndrade horas, não leve a mal, senso de humor é essencial, só achei estranho o "anos" ali, sendo que tua conta no SOen tem apenas 100 pontos e 7 meses de "vida", não entenda mal, mas esta sua história `Esses dias ganhei vários votos em vários comentários da mesma pessoa e acabei sendo punido` não faz sentido, não existe punição para isto, muito menos se for em comentários, quero dizer, deve ter acontecido algo que você compreendeu errado, uma coisa é punição, outra coisa é reversão, leia isto https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5952/3635 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/3635 ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já não é a primeira vez que sempre aparece um ixperrrtão, mais esperto que os outros... rs meu SOpt está com 520 pts, faz 1 mês que "participo ativamente. Não participo do en, que está com 101. "-75 03:02 reversão Votação corrigida (saiba mais)" link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed abraços

Comment: @DiegoAndrade Isso é uma coisa comum. Da mesma forma que ocorreu a reversão dos upvotes, teria ocorrido se fossem downvotes. [Nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5513/20615) você pode ler mais sobre o assunto

Comment: @DiegoAndrade como eu disse, ninguem esta te ofendendo, a ideia aqui mostrar que houve confusão, apenas aceite a ajuda e criticas construtivas, estava claro que vc compreendeu duas coisas de maneira equivocada, por algo tão bobo assim se chatear chega a ser bastante exagero... esta mensagem que vc recebeu não tem nada haver com **punição**, é apenas um sistema anti-fraudes, outro dia eu dei 3 upvotes em pontagens de uma mesma pessoa e horas depois foram revertidos, nem eu e nem a pessoa fomos punidos, o proprio link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed explica.

Comment: @Randrade Show, obrigado pela explicação, pra mim foi novidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento show, entendi a mensagem que vc quis passar e fico agradecido. Mas no geral, grande parte aqui não faz "críticas construtivas" e sim, tentam se mostrar melhores uns que os outros. Na boa, eu adoro ser corrigido, Aceito de muito bom grado uma crítica construtiva, mas na maioria das vezes não é essa intenção aqui. No mais, valeu pela explicação e bom dia pra vcs :D

Comment: @DiegoAndrade raramente vi algo assim, as vezes a pessoa entende mais mesmo e esta simplesmente tentando lhe ajudar, se souber ser receptivo talvez ajude a ver com melhores olhos, eu tenho um colega bastante estressado, ele geralmente conversa com os outros sem cerimonias e sempre parece um grosseiro devido a isto, mas ele sempre esta ajudando e dando dicas para usuários mais novos, é que por texto as vezes é dificil se expressar, até mais :D

Answer (score 11):

Discordo totalmente da opinião do Daniel Omine nesta parte:

> Ou seja mantém membros feito bobos trabalhando de graça em troca de estrelinhas que não valem nada. Isso funciona bem, os donos enchem os bolsos de dinheiro e o site ganha conteúdo valioso de graça. Por isso a ludificação é importante.

Concordo *"parcialmente"* com isto:

> Qualquer coisa que um membro como o bigown posta, "imediatamente" ganha 10, 20 votos (exemplo, ok?). Mas se outro membro qualquer tivesse postado exatamente o mesmo, é ignorado. Recebe uns 2 ou 3 votos no máximo. Isso cria até uma desconfiança sobre a credibilidade do sistema. Dá impressão de que o sistema do SO privilegia um ou outro usuário específico ligado ou próximo a administração. Colocando em dúvida se isso é mesmo uma comunidade e até mesmo se os votos são reais.

Sim, existe isso, mas não é culpa do *"sistema"*

### Gamification/Ludificação

Isso eu nem vou entrar muito em detalhes, mas o sistema de Q&A e pontos no *stackoverflow.com* mostrou ser um sucesso, afinal quais são os sites que os programadores mais procuram? Então como os sistemas de fórum sem pontos fazem menos sucesso? Alguém pode explicar?

Não estou elogiando ou dizendo que o sistema de *ludificação* seja perfeito, mas obviamente mostrou ser um sucesso, acreditem ou não.

> Eu concordo plenamente que não deveria existir a ludificação (gamefication) pois causa esses problemas de ordem social e afetam diretamente o que interessa que é o conteúdo técnico.

Eu já participei de 7 fóruns, todos sem gamefication, o tipo de conteúdo meia boca era muito popular nestes fóruns e o conteúdo bom não tinha destaque ou ia para o limbo em pouco tempo, fora que o não tinha pouco valor técnico ou "documental" o que valia lá era o assistencialismo

### A Stack Overflow ganha dinheiro com nosso trabalho e nos faz trabalhar de graça?

Isto foi o maior exagero que li na postagem:

> mantém membros feito bobos trabalhando de graça em troca de estrelinhas

Até aonde sei todos se beneficiam, o conteúdo é compartilhado com [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (requer [atribuir](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)), não é conteúdo privado é conteúdo compartilhado, você veem aqui e aprende de graça, copia de graça, consegue até suporte de graça, a *Stack Overflow* ganha sim dinheiro com a popularidade e com o [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) e só.

Quero que prestem atenção, a *Stack Overflow* disponibiliza um sistema para nos relacionarmos, compartilharmos, chat para interagirmos isso em escala internacional, isso com:

- O custo de 9 servidores (ou mais), veja os detalhes em:

  - http://docplayer.com.br/3642486-A-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow.html
  - https://stackexchange.com/about/performance
- Equipe de suporte para os servidores
- Um membro da *staff* pelo menos por site

*(Perguntas retóricas >>>)*

- Você realmente acreditam *Stack Overflow* tem que manter todos sites da rede de graça?
- Quer dizer que só a *Stack Overflow* se beneficia dos sites da rede?
- Nós não chegamos aqui e pegamos suporte de outros membros de graça?
- Então quer dizer que dava pra ser *tudo comunitário*, lindo e de graça, inclusive como a SO pagar pelos servidores e funcionários, ou os funcionários também trabalhariam de graça?

**Não**, eles tem o direito de ter algum retorno pra manter a equipe e os servidores e nós membros aprendemos com o conteúdo e evoluímos por compartilhar.

### Somos um sucesso e não precisamos mais do sistema de votos

Parece que ao ler isto:

> A ludificação é importante e ajudou a rede a crescer. Mas atualmente a rede SO já tem uma marca reconhecida. Não precisa mais disso.

As pessoas entendem que os pontos são apenas para os usuários? Realmente é só isso que usuários enxergarem? Os pontos são principalmente para avaliar o conteúdo, claro que como eu já disse nada é perfeito, mas tem muita coisa que da para ter uma noção com base nos votos, quem avalia somos nós, isto é extremamente importante para pelo menos termos uma noção

Eliminem o sistema e pronto seremos igual a qualquer outro site que já existe, se eles são tão bons porque não tem tanto sucesso? Um exemplo é aquele fórum do Google para programadores até suporte técnico (quando lembrar do link eu mando aqui), é internacional, possui vários idiomas, mas nem mesmo eu lembro dele, o conteúdo lá mesmo sendo um pouco organizado não tinha gamefication e nem como avaliar direito o que é bom, só tinha destaque pra resposta escolhida pelo autor e pronto, era um Q&A que o autor mesmo que equivocadamente decide que é melhor, a resposta escolhida fica no topo e maior, as demais ficam meio que minimizadas.

### Dá impressão de que o sistema do SO privilegia

Se estiver falado do sistema ou da empresa, isto não faz sentido, se estiver falando da comunidade faz "um pouco" de sentido:

> Dá impressão de que o sistema do SO privilegia um ou outro usuário específico ligado ou próximo a administração. Colocando em dúvida se isso é mesmo uma comunidade e até mesmo se os votos são reais.

**Ninguém nega** que temos problemas com ups e downs, principalmente com upvotes, eu mesmo já reclamei disto, até o próprio bigown já reclamou, não tem hipócritas aqui, pelo menos entre os veteranos e mais participativos creio que não tenha, a maior parte de nós já reclamamos disto, mas vou deixar bem claro apesar de alguns usuários ganharem **upvotes na maioria das vezes** são votos bem merecidos, eu pessoalmente acho que 5 fatores influenciam em como a comunidade vota:

- Confiança no usuário que respondeu, um usuário como o bigown já mostrou seu conhecimento e saber do que esta falando, isso gera a confiança e aumenta a credibilidade, não minha nem sua, mas da maioria da comunidade
- Citar fontes de modo coerente, tem gente que só sai colando os links de referencia sem apontar a necessidade daquilo no texto, fica algo solto
- Maneira de escrever, de passar o conhecimento
- Maneira de escrever o título + "tags" de interesse, tem tags que por incrível que pareça atraem mais visitantes, inclusive tem alguns que não sabem, mas tem como seguir as tags e elas tem até feeds e tem muita gente que usa
- Horário da postagem, este é um fator fraco e que influencia um pouco menos que os outros, mas no geral influencia também

Claro que tem uma série de outros fatores, como tempo que fica ativo postando novas respostas, assistencialismo, saber fazer um "marketing" pessoal (compartilhar em outras mídias suas postagens), mas eu pessoalmente não posso falar muito disto, porque o foco nem é explicar como ganhar votos (ou perder).

### Deixar de votar por antipatia

Agora vou deixar bem claro, além de alguns ups por empatia, também existe quem deixa de votar por ter criado antipatia, havia alguns usuários que tenho certeza que votavam em respostas minhas, mas houve alguns desentendimentos (não foram brigas, mas sim opiniões diferentes), após isto notei quem meus upvotes diminuíram, mesmo que eu me esforça-se para citar fontes, detalhes e exemplos notei que passei a receber em média 1 a 3 upvotes e isso leva as vezes dias, sim assim como existe **alguns** que votam por empatia também existem **alguns** que deixam de votar por antipatia, mesmo que as respostas sejam boa e úteis.

### Os votos são exclusivamente porque gosto de um outro usuário

Existir isto existe, como já disse, mas o favoritismo veem devido a credibilidade, não que seja um fator que vá impedir de votar errado, mas nem todos *upvotes free* são devido a isto:

> A ideia não é ocultar 100%, mas sim coibir os votos baseados em popularidade, emotividade ou favoritismo.

Eu vejo muita resposta terrível de usuários na média de 2k ~ 10k que tem sérios problemas ganhando até +5, inclusive nos últimos 3 meses acompanhei cerca de 12 usuários que respondiam coisas falhas eu tentei os orientar e apontar aonde estava o problema, acabei tendo alguns problemas por causa disto, mas o fato não é este e sim que uma coisa que notei, todos eles ganhavam entre 3 a 5 upvotes facilmente, mesmo tendo problemas em suas respostas, então digo o problema do upvote não é só o favoritismo, na verdade nem é o favoritismo, o problema é:

**Muitos usuários novos e alguns veteranos votam sem ler ou testar ou porque uma gambiarra funcionou de primeira**

Isto **é** opinião, mas baseado no que conheço e acompanho, ou seja as pessoas não confiam só em quem tem credibilidade, muitas confiam em quase qualquer coisa que leem sem pesquisar pra confirmar, ao meu ver este é o mesmo problema das pessoas na redes sociais e mensageiros (email, whatsapp, etc), quando chega uma noticia ou boato a pessoa não pesquisa se é real simplesmente compartilha e isto vira um ciclo que vai aumentando, o mesmo acontece com as pessoas que votam, independente se a pessoa que respondeu é um usuário de pontuação alta, a sociedade é assim e aqui não é diferente porque a sociedade é a mesma.

Não é um problema do sistema só (como disse o sistema não é perfeito, mas ainda sim funciona bem), é também um fator externo.

Comment: Sobre essa parte "**Somos um sucesso e não precisamos mais do sistema de votos**" eu não discordo em nada de você, mas queria acrescentar que se o sistema mudasse para os votos serem pela qualidade do post (pergunta e resposta) e não retornasse em pontos para o usuário que os fez, alguns usuários ativos no site iriam parar de responder. Eu notei que alguns usuários fazem de tudo apenas para ganhar votos e aumentar a reputação.

Comment: Não que isso seja ruim, pois muitas vezes melhora a qualidade do post. Porém, existem usuários que não aceitam "perder" (accept ou pontos) e acabam deixando uma situação desconfortável para alguns outros, especialmente para aqueles que acabaram de chegar no site.

Comment: @Randrade como eu disse: ele não é perfeito, o intuito é melhorar e não remover, o Daniel falou de remover pq não precisamos, eu acredito que precisamos é apenas aprimorar :) ... o mesmo que vc disse

Comment: Por isso que disse que não discordo de você :p

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução mais simples seria cooperação de todos ou pelo menos da maioria, mas como isso é "impossível", a opção seria uma mudança na estrutura da rede SO.

Contudo, essa opção é também inviável pois a estrutura, o modelo de negócios em si, é baseada na ludificação. Ou seja mantém membros feito bobos trabalhando de graça em troca de estrelinhas que não valem nada. Isso funciona bem, os donos enchem os bolsos de dinheiro e o site ganha conteúdo valioso de graça. Por isso a ludificação é importante.

Eu concordo plenamente que não deveria existir a ludificação(gameficação) pois causa esses problemas de ordem social e afetam diretamente o que interessa que é o conteúdo técnico.

O ideal seria algo anônimo como no Wikipedia. No Wikipedia você pode ver os nomes dos colaboradores que fica escondido nas entranhas administrativas de edição de uma determinada página. Assim, ninguém fica disputando egos e concentra-se exclusivamente na produção de conteúdo.

A ludificação traz esse mal que é a disputa de egos, cria grupos isolados de pessoas com mais afinidade uma com outra, gerando rachas e ilhas isoladas na comunidade.

Como já comentado, influencia na votação e até colaboração do conteúdo. Um sujeito deixa de ajudar na formação do conteúdo porque o autor original é alguém de quem ele não gosta. Ou deixa de votar positivo mesmo o conteúdo sendo muito bom porque leva mais em consideração o lado emotivo. Também vota negativo em qualquer brecha quando é alguém de quem não gosta, do contrário, até ajuda alguém que gosta a corrigir um erro para não tomar negativo. Vota somente nos que já são populares com muitos pontos, o que desequilibra o ambiente.

Cria-se também a falsa impressão de que quem tem mais pontos, tem maior conhecimento naquilo que posta e isso é um ledo engano.

É comum ver membros pedindo que a resposta seja dada por bigown ou bacco. Nada contra ambos pois possuem alta pontuação por mérito deles mesmos, mas esse é um exemplo claro do efeito que causa.

Qualquer coisa que um membro como o bigown posta, "imediatamente" ganha 10, 20 votos (exemplo, ok?). Mas se outro membro qualquer tivesse postado exatamente o mesmo, é ignorado. Recebe uns 2 ou 3 votos no máximo. Isso cria até uma desconfiança sobre a credibilidade do sistema. Dá impressão de que o sistema do SO privilegia um ou outro usuário específico ligado ou próximo a administração. Colocando em dúvida se isso é mesmo uma comunidade e até mesmo se os votos são reais.

Até em comentários você vê a brutal diferença. Todos os outros são ignorados mas se membros como os que citei postam, recebem um monte de positivo mesmo existindo outros execelentes comentários.

Por fim, há uma série de consequências a partir daí e se avaliarmos bem, é tudo inútil pois o importante, que deveria ser o conteúdo técnico, fica num segundo plano, ofuscado por estrelismos e disputas de ego.

É até perigoso pois quem tem mais pontos consegue influenciar outros com opinião própria, impondo o seu próprio gosto. Falo até por mim mesmo. Quando eu posto respostas onde outros com menor pontuação do que eu postam, eu sou mais privilegiado mesmo existindo respostas melhores. E isso não deveria ser assim.

Há um ano pensei em abrir a mesma discussão aqui no meta, mas pensei “será mesmo?”. Desisti pois cheguei a conclusão de que nada poderia ser feito devido aos motivos acima citados. Uma grande mudança no modelo de negócios não parece ser algo possível. Isso dependerá da gestão. De quem administra a rede. Ou seja, os chefes, os donos.

Eu não sabia que alguém já tinha aberto essa discussão em 2015 e fico de certa forma esperançoso de que isso se torne realidade algum dia. Acredito que se houver maior demanda, a mudança pode vir a acontecer.

## Ocultar nomes por período curto

Essa ideia de ocultar por um período é bacana pois acredito que as pessoas votariam no conteúdo. Os que votam por favoritismo ou influência da quantidade de pontos que determinado membro possui, pensariam melhor e teríamos um ambiente mais justo. Porém, prefiro que não seja exibido os nomes de quem posta. Isso poderia ser mais burocrático como no wikipedia. Só exibir os nomes a partir de uma página de administração acessível por quem tem mais de 10 ou 20 mil pontos, por exemplo.

Também poderia ser feito um experimento num único site e não na rede toda.  Normalmente quem vota sem pensar só faz aquilo no momento e esquece. Nem vai se dar ao trabalho de voltar e reler o assunto.

A ideia não é ocultar 100%, mas sim coibir os votos baseados em popularidade, emotividade ou favoritismo. Assim poderia manter ainda o sistema do jeito que é, sem drásticas mudanças. Um simples JavaScript com CSS programados para exibir os nomes depois de uns 5 dias, seria suficiente. Acho 5 minutos muito curto.

Enfim, existem várias formas de resolver, só precisa de **boa vontade**.

Quem é contra tal mudança, é porque se beneficia do sistema do jeito é e vai sempre arrumar alguma desculpa, algum probleminha para que não aconteça. Ou simplesmente porque não tem vontade alguma em criar soluções.

## Eliminação total da ludificação?

A ludificação é importante e ajudou a rede a crescer. Mas atualmente a rede SO já tem uma marca reconhecida. Não precisa mais disso.

Eliminando ou bloqueando esse recurso acabaremos com muitos dos problemas que nos fazem perder o foco e perder tempo em coisas paralelas e dispersas.

Aqui no meta, muito se discute sobre assuntos inúteis. É mimimi fulano votou negativo, mimimi beltrano não gosta de mim...

Tem páginas de ranking que incentivam a disputa. Membros passam a buscar mais pontos não se importando com conteúdo.

Precisamos de mais foco no desenvolvimento, acelerar e focar em produção de conteúdo útil.

Problemas novos surgirão, com certeza, mas não serão piores do que os problemas do modelo atual.

Se um membro descobre quem postou e resolve votar negativo, isso pode ser detectado pelo sistema e o membro sofrer punição. Isso já acontece.

Comment: Não creio que a ludificação seja tão ruim assim, pois alguns usuário se esforçam mais para gerar bom conteúdo para sim ganhar mais pontos, o que esta totalmente correto ja que ele esta gerando um conteúdo de qualidade e gostaria de ganhar o devido mérito. O problema ja observado e que você mesmo pos é justamente o voto emocional/com logica fraca (ele tem muitos pontos então a resposta deve ser boa). A questão da exibição do AP e pontos da P/R é que deve ser realmente analisado e ter foco, quem sabe monta algo para isso.

Comment: Não creio que a exibição por timer resolva, pois quando pesquisamos por algo pode ter se passada alguns dias, então estará tudo exibido o que geraria o mesmo problema, creio que deveria ser apos uma ação do usuário.

Comment: Uma coisa que poderia ser feita em questão da exibição AP e pontos, é não exibir nenhum tipo de ponto para 3º, apenas para o priprio AP, assim o AP sabe quantos votos esta ganhando e continua querendo desenvolver resposta de qualidade devido a ludificação, mas so ele sabe os pontos ganhos.

Comment: A emotividade gera ação por impulso, normalmente algo de momento. Por isso acho que um tempo de curto de 5min. ou 5hs é insuficiente. O sujeito ainda tenderá a reverter o voto por emotividade. No caso do tempo de 5 dias, por exemplo, a cabeça do neguinho já esfriou e ele até já esqueceu e inclusive vai estar pegando no pé de outros rsrsrs. Esse tempo maior é mais como inibidor mesmo. Conforme citei, e você também, não tem como impedir totalmente mas o sistema pode coibir. E se o sujeito insistir com picuinha, tem o sistema que pode detectar atitudes de má fé. Isso já existe inclusive.

Comment: A ludificação pode sim fazer que alguns formatem melhor as respostas mas creio que sem ludificação as respostas de boa qualidade existiriam do mesmo jeito. Remover o sistema seria drástico demais pois é praticamente intrínsico da rede SO e temos que aceitar pois de qualquer maneira, o modelo tem funcionado e a rede é um grande sucesso mundial. Temos que reconhecer isso também. Mas fica aí uma opinião de como poderia renovar o business model considerando que a rede já possui um nome valioso e não precisa mais "ludificar" os usuários com estrelinhas, chapeus, medalinhas, gif animado... rsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine o que separa este site de todos fóruns existentes até hoje é precisamente isso, a ludificação, que separa o conteúdo muito mau, mau, médio, bom e muito bom. O sistema pode até estar com problemas, mas é melhor que qualquer outro existente até hoje. Como eu vou saber que uma resposta é boa ou má? No SOen, que ainda hoje em dia eu uso muito para pesquisa, mais até que o SOpt, eu vejo sempre a resposta a seguir à marcada como certa, a ver se tem melhor pontuação, se tiver passo logo para essa. Se não tivesse esse sistema teria de andar a ver as respostas todas (...)

Comment: (...) e por consequência passaria exatamente a ter qualquer coisa como um fórum. Para além de que a  pontuação ganha pode realmente ter um benefício na sua vida. Há alguns casos desses aqui. Não é só a SE que saia a lucrar, os utilizadores também. Fora o conhecimento... Há problemas de upvote como «like» do facebook? Há mas a forma de os resolver não é eliminar uma coisa boa, é sim tentar encontrar um solução para esse problema, mantendo a ideia que é boa.

Comment: @DanielOmine por último não é porque já têm fama que agora podem retirar o que lhes deu a fama toda, além de correrem o risco de destruir  trabalho de uma vida estão a desvalorizar os utilizadores que se esforçaram por obter pontuação, estrelinha, chapéus, etc. Competição, desde que seja saudável, é sempre bem vinda.

Comment: @DanielOmine agora mesmo para terminar ;) vou dar +1 por ter dado esse ponto de vista, é importante discutir todos os pontos de vista e quiça usar um bocadinho de cada um para construir uma solução para o problema. (Como pode ver nem sempre o +1 quer dizer o que parece ;) e nem sempre quer dizer que seja mau)