# Quais os limites para entrar na regra de fraude de votação?

Tags: debate, votos

Foi recentemente que comecei a construir com mais afinco minha reputação aqui, mas, estou indo devagar e cada pontinho é suado e comemorado. Um dia desses, pela manhã, me deparei com 65 novos pontos na minha conta, e fiquei intrigado. Então descobri que alguma alma caridosa devia ter visto alguma(s) resposta(s) minha(s), gostou e foi dar uma olhada no resto das minhas perguntas e respostas, escolheu algumas que achou boas (mais precisamente 6 respostas e 1 pergunta) e votou a favor delas como úteis.

Fiquei muito feliz, senti meu trabalho reconhecido, e comecei a pensar em fazer a mesma coisa com outras pessoas, porque enquanto participo das filas de análise, e passeando pelo site, encontro outras pessoas que também estão começando, com menos de mil de reputação, que ajudam bastante nos comentários, e às vezes dão boas respostas, e receber uma leva de votos úteis assim, é bem estimulante.

Mas, no dia seguinte, acabou a alegria, os 65 pontos foram varridos da minha conta. Nesse momento me dei conta então dessa regra do site, que reverte votos em série para evitar **[fraude de votação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)**. No começo fiquei "p* da vida" e me senti injustiçado, mas, depois aceitei, é uma regra e é justa, não beneficia nem um lado nem outro. De fato, se a pessoa trabalha em uma empresa em que todos os outros programadores estão inscritos no SO, e ainda tem amigos programadores inscritos, pode realmente acontecer isso, de combinarem para uns votarem nos outros, então, é uma regra justa.

Mas agora fico pensando: qual é o limite de votos e o limite de tempo entre um voto e outro, para o mesmo usuário, para que uma ação de votos em série caia nessa regra?

Porque eu tenho tentado votar mais, à medida que vou encontrando boas mensagens pelo caminho, que é a ideia do site, e também porque tenho sentido o mesmo que tenho lido em muitas mensagens antigas do meta: as pessoas votam pouco (e no SOpt as pessoas gostam muito de dar votos negativos logo de cara também).

Mas, por exemplo, todos sabem que é inevitável, ao passear por aí entre as boas respostas, muitas delas, mas muitas mesmo, são do **Maniero**, e outros usuários com grande reputação, então, fiquei com medo de cair na regra ao sair votando em várias respostas do Maniero, por exemplo, porque a regra reverte não só os pontos que a pessoa ganhou com meus votos, mas também os votos em si, então, teria sido um desperdício de tempo.

Comment: A questão não gira em torno da regra ou dos pontos. Deve-se votar em posts e não em pessoas. Se está entrando numa conta de alguém e votando nessa pessoa, já tem um problema, independente de reversão ou não. Em regra, quando você esbarra num bom post, deve positivar, um "neutro" deixe como está, um ruim negative. Quer achar coisas boas pra votar? Pesquise por uma tag ou assunto que goste. Importante notar que mesmo o sistema não revertendo automaticamente, votos "visados" são passíveis de punição. O sistema automático é só para coisas "gritantes", mas definitivamente não é o único mecanismo.

Comment: Creio que o essencial está respondido aqui, mas estou procurando outras discussões para complementar https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5513/70

Comment: Sim, eu sei, mas veja o meu ponto: eu fui responder uma pergunta sobre alocação de memória em C, pesquisei sobre o assunto e quis colocar links de outras respostas para complementar a minha. Pesquisei sobre a função `free()` e achei uma boa resposta, do Maniero, votei a favor. Pesquisei sobre alinhamento de memória para alocação de estruturas, achei uma boa resposta, do Maniero, votei a favor. Pesquisei sobre estouro de pilha, achei uma boa resposta, do Maniero. Aí parei pra pensar, já serão 3 votos seguidos em respostas do Maniero, será que cairei na regra de fraude?

Comment: Já aconteceu com praticamente todos nós que temos tempo de site :D mas as regras não são tão exatas assim (tem vários fatores) e não só podem mudar, como determinar elas vai servir mais para ajudar quem quer fraudar do que pra tomar cuidado. Vá pelo seu bom senso que tudo funciona ;)

Comment: Em geral votos em mim não são revertidos :) Fui descobrindo isso aos poucos. Não que não possa, mas se não for nada muito exagerado não é mais. No começo era. O sistema tem pesos de acordo com uma série de circunstâncias. Provavelmente o sistema identifica que há um padrão muito grande de votos em mim. Não acho justo ter votos em sequência quando a pessoa só quer me dar pontos, mas é justo quando ocorre o mesmo que você fez, eu tenho muitas respostas canônicas e é comum ter alguns votos assim, mas o sistema é esperto o suficiente para identificar que não foi malícia e não reverte.

Comment: Já me aconteceu o inverso antes da moderação, um mesmo usuário postou uma série de porcarias, eu negativei várias sem notar de quem era, e reverteu. Os negativos eram merecidos, mas aquela condição específica acabou fazendo com que parecesse perseguição.

Comment: Como comentado [nesta resposta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268747), os critérios exatos não são divulgados justamente para não ajudar os fraudadores. Se eles soubessem que o sistema reverte depois de N votos, eles parariam no N - 1, por exemplo. Mesmo com regras mais complexas, como combinação de votos em um espaço de tempo, etc (estou chutando pq eu também não sei a regra), daria para saber os limites e até onde ir para não reverter. Tem o efeito colateral de reverter votos positivos legítimos, mas acho que mesmo assim não vão divulgar o critério.

Comment: @Maniero, ontem li muitas perguntas e respostas e dei vários votos, tanto que acabei ganhando as medalhas Sufrágio e Vox Populi, mas hoje quando entrei vi que haviam 16 votos a menos, do total de votos que tinha ontem. Embora o sistema não mostre para mim os votos revertidos, fui entrando na minha lista de votos recentes e descobri que os que não estavam mais lá eram justamente... os seus! É estranho, porque os votos nem foram próximos, foram ao longo do dia.

Comment: @PedroGaspar É, exagero muito grande complica :) Eu vi que teve votos revertidos em mim mesmo. Por isso que eu coloquei "em geral". Quando começa ter muitos pode haver reversão, essa coisa de ser perto não é um critério absoluto, o sistema é mais esperto que isso, não vou entrar em detalhes do que eu já percebi para não despertar ninguém fazendo de sacanagem. Eu sei que você está com interesse genuíno, lendo e aproveitando o conteúdo antes de votar, mas nem todos fazem por isso. Se for votar de novo, vai com um pouco mais de calma.