# Como indicar múltiplas perguntas na sinalização de pergunta duplicada?

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas, sinalização

Outro dia eu fiz uma pergunta aqui no Meta que já havia sido discutida, e ela foi marcada como duplicada, com múltiplas perguntas similares:

[Quais os limites para entrar na regra de fraude de votação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7430/86952)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Entretanto, quando vou sinalizar uma pergunta como duplicada, parece não haver forma de indicar mais de uma pergunta similar ao mesmo tempo (o que não é muito raro):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Também parece que depois que sinalizo uma pergunta, não posso fazer outra sinalização para a mesma pergunta.

Essa colocação de múltiplas perguntas similares em uma duplicada é edição do moderador que aceitou a sinalização, ou existe alguma forma de indicar mais de uma pergunta na tela de sinalização de duplicada?

Comment: vc pode adicionar mais links depois que ela for fechada desde que tenha o privilegio.

Comment: Somente moderadores ou usuários que tenham medalha de ouro em qualquer uma das tags da pergunta podem adicionar mais de uma duplicata após a pergunta ser fechada.

Comment: Mas não seria uma funcionalidade interessante de acrescentar ? Acabava poupando tempo dos moderadores em achar mais duplicatas, tempo este que é precioso.

Comment: @Isac uai, mas a funcionalidade ta ai ja, é só o autor ter a medalha de ouro na tag :D

Comment: Pode postar links que vc achar nos comentarios e marcar quem fechou tambem, quando vejo perguntas duplicatas, eu sempre vejo os links q postam nos comentarios e adiciono se sao relevantes

Comment: @Articunohexacampão A funcionalidade era em relação a sinalizar múltiplas duplicatas numa só sinalização, assim sendo a sinalização aceite, já estava tudo feito, não sendo necessário acrescentar nenhum link manualmente por ninguém.

Comment: @Articunohexacampão acho q vc deu a resposta, não?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderadores podem alterar a lista de perguntas mostradas nesse "header" depois do fechamento da pergunta. Mas, isso à parte, a lista pode ter mais do que uma pergunta se os utilizadores votarem para fechar como duplicada de **mais do que uma pergunta** — ou seja, se tu (e mais dois utilizadores, vamos supor) votares como duplicada da pergunta A, outro utilizador da B, e outro ainda da C, as três (A, B, e C) deveriam aparecer na lista quando a pergunta for fechada.

Quando em dúvida sobre como acabámos com tantos nomes na lista, podes sempre olhar para [o timeline da pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7430/timeline).

Comment: Seria legal se desse para fazer isso que o @Bacco fez: `5132,5513,1886,930`, direto lá na caixa de sinalização de duplicata! :-)

Comment: Isto só é possível para os moderadores (e, se não estou em erro, utilizadores com medalhas de ouro em tags) porque não queremos que seja abusado — por vezes é preciso limpas a lista, ou acrescentar uma pergunta extra à lista, etc., mas na maior parte dos casos apontar para uma única publicação é preferível visto que queremos tentar concentrar o conhecimento num só sítio, em vez de mandar os utilizadores numa "caça ao tesouro" pela lista de perguntas duplicadas. E neste caso... o próprio Bacco disse que tinha "abusado" um bocado da funcionalidade quando falámos ;)