# Sequência de "upvote" pode limitar pontos ganhos honestamente no dia?

Tags: debate, serial-voting, duvida, pontos

Vou tentar explicar em poucas palavras criando um cenário bem plausível.

*Primeiro*, imagine que você responde muito em uma *tag*, ou é um usuário antigo e tem várias respostas entre as 30 mais votadas na *tag*.

*Segundo*, imagine que em um dia qualquer você já está com **150 pontos honestos**, e algum *"bounty hunter"* querendo por exemplo as medalhas [Vox Populi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi), ou [Sufrágio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage), ou [Dever cívico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty), entrou na *tag* que você tem muitas respostas e saiu dando *upvote* em pelo menos 5 ou 7 das suas respostas.

Isso te deixaria com 200 a 220 pontos, dos quais 50 a 70 foram uma "sequência" de votos que podem ser removidos pelo sistema, pois pode ser considerada como fraude no sistema de pontos.

**Agora vem a pergunta:** Imagine que você está com esses 200+ pontos *(dos quais 50 "desonestos" serão anulados de qualquer forma)*, e você ganha mais 50 pontos honestamente, esses 50 além dos 200 diários não serão computados? Então vou perder os 50+ da sequência de votos do *"bounty hunter"* e ainda vou deixar de ganhar os 50 pontos honestos que vieram depois dessa sequência de votos?

<sub>*Desculpe se ficou um pouco confuso, se não ficou claro todos os pontos é só comentar que tento melhorar o texto*</sub>

Comment: Aproveitando a pergunta, qual seria o motivo de sequências de upvotes? Tenho sofrido isso com certa frequência. Antes eu sofria sequências de downvotes, mas tenho notado que quase toda semana aparecem 4 ou 5 upvotes em sequência em postagens antigas minhas. Mas, em contrapartida, vez em quando esses pontos são estornados com a mensagem "_usuário removido_".

Comment: @Sam não sei dizer ao certo pq isso acontece... como sugeri na pergunta acredito que possa ser os "casadores de medalhas" votando na tag que ele tem mais afinidade e que por coincidência vc tem mais respostas... Agora mesmo temos um *hat* que é para quem der 150 votos... Então é previsto que o número de votos suba devido os "caçadores de chapéus" ... Mas é só teoria não posso afirmar isso

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De acordo com o [FAQ do meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/401803):

> **Reversals trigger a reputation recalculation.**
>
> Whenever serial voting gets reversed, all days involved in the serial voting will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never happened, and any reputation you might have lost due to those serial votes hitting the reputation cap will be given to you at that time. Serial voters will not prevent you from gaining reputation that you deserve.

Em tradução livre:

> **Reversões fazem a reputação ser recalculada**
>
> Sempre que votos em sequência forem revertidos, todos os dias envolvidos nesta votação serão recalculados como se os votos em sequência nunca tivessem acontecido, e qualquer reputação que você teria perdido por atingir o limite (*no caso, os 200 pontos diários*) serão dados a você neste momento. *Serial voters* não te impedirão de ganhar a reputação que você merece.

Resumindo, no seu exemplo, caso os votos do "*bounty hunter*" sejam revertidos (o que, segundo o mesmo FAQ, ocorre diariamente às 03:00 UTC e o [critério exato para reversão não é divulgado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7430/112052)), os 50 pontos honestos serão dados.

Comment: Acho que era isso que eu procurava! É bom saber que estamos resguardados quanto a isso. Obrigado por responder

Comment: @hugocsl Quando respondi fiquei em dúvida se tinha entendido sua pergunta, que bom que entendi :-)

Comment: Foi difícil mesmo relatar essa dúvida sem deixar o texto confuso rss. Mas a resposta caiu como uma luva!